# Dropbox has limited amount of connections. Any ways to fix it?

Tags: dropbox

Basic Dropbox users have a three device limit as of March 2019. Are there any solutions to bypass this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

As for me, this problem could be easily solved. I advise to use CloudMounter, it's a third-party app which allows connecting Dropbox account from an unlimited amount of devices. Because in this case, connection via third-party app isn't followed as a linked device.